# Subresource Integrity security header on Firebase

Tags: firebase, http-headers, cors, onesignal, subresource-integrity

**SRI - Subresource Integrity security feature on Firebase**

- I want to implement Subresource Integrity security feature on
  Firebase.
- My push notifications are OneSignal Website basic setup, served by
  CDN, but now i'm dealing with CORS issues.
- Tried to white list the oneSignal CDN via Access-Control-Allow-Origin
  header, but didn't worked.

Any advice on this? Thanks a lot!

index.html

```
    <!-- OneSignal -->
    <script src="https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/OneSignalSDK.js" integrity="sha256-t1LT+Y2Mggg3CziqvOSn//47ekhB3IWvczG5g5pZF5I= sha384-vVrIVOhTb6P+4WMvVY4OhcO9b04Pt1kfcrkiTi3q8b/MG7kRwiNSIuhmKBnlKA3W sha512-zI/26urvS8F5oBQj4MChQbf8jVDP06RucbNYHuTguAxo3h8PXgFlM175kxarwnM9y0wTVjGAXe5JWIHsRMK2kw==" crossorigin="anonymous" async></script>
```

firebase.json

```
  "headers": [
    {
      "source": "**",
      "headers": [
        {
          "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
          "value": "https://cdn.onesignal.com/"
        },
        {
          "key": "Vary",
          "value": "Origin"
        }
      ]
    }
 ]
```

Note: For subresource-integrity verification of a resource served from an origin other than the document in which it’s embedded, browsers additionally check the resource using Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS), to ensure the origin serving the resource allows it to be shared with the requesting origin.
[Subresource_Integrity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting your function to public?
Don't know if that's actually what you're looking for though.
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access-iam#allowing_unauthenticated_function_invocation

Comment: I was using spark free plan, and not using functions that was the problem....

So the way to call outside of google domains with the functions is only doable under a paid plan ...

and you are right that's the link pointing to solution.

thanks!